# HTML - How to include padding/margin of the parent element in width percentage of current element?

Tags: html, css, width, margin

I am rendering a hierarchy structure of my organization, that has two columns: Name and People. because each hierarchy element can belong to different hierarchy level, I use margin-left css property to distinguish those. But when I set the width of Name div to 80%, and the width of People div to 20%, the width appear to be different for each level, because they do not include the margin property of a parent element:
[image]

Currently my HTML structure looks like so:
[image]

And the CSS styles applied are the following:

```
.item-name, .item-count {
    word-break: break-all;
    line-height:22pt;
    font-size:10pt;
    border: solid 1px grey;
    padding: 4px;
    display: inline-block;
}
.item-name {
    width:80%;
}
.item-count {
    text-align:center;
    width:20%;
}
```

What should I do to make the width:80% and width:20% include the margin width of a parent div, whatever margin value that is?

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't/how to make this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the **shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself**. See: [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

I know this is not the best solution, but the following trick worked for me (250px ~ 20%):

```
.item-count {
    text-align:center;
    width:250px;
}
```

And then each div with item-name class contains inline style with width property calculated based on parent's width and margin:

```
<div class="item-row" style="margin-left:25px;">
    <div class="item-name id-2_2031" style="width:calc(80% + (25px * 0.8) - 25px)">
    </div>
    <div class="item-count">
    </div>
</div>
```

...

```
<div class="item-row" style="margin-left:50px;">
    <div class="item-name id-2_2031" style="width:calc(80% + (50px * 0.8) - 50px)">
    </div>
    <div class="item-count">
    </div>
</div>
```